# Django doesn't recognize my static folder

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I just started my django project and i saw that i had to put my static folder in my project folder so i did, i think i did the necessary modifications to settings.py but when a ran my server, the css wasn't applying to my page, i looked at where my css file was looked for and it said "404 /store/static/css/carousel.css" ("store" is my app inside my project) while it should look for "myproject/static/css/carousel.css".

So I moved my static folder inside my app folder ("store") at the location the server was looking for (store/static/css/carousel.css) but even if it is now looking at the right location it is still not working.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')]
```

html page referencing my css file

```
{% extends 'store/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block head %}
<link href="{% static 'css/carousel.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
```

server response

```
Not Found: /store/static/css/carousel.css
[07/Aug/2023 10:00:27] "GET /store/static/css/carousel.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2378
```

i have these directories

```
.
├── myproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── store
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── carousel.css
    │   │   ├── main.css
    │   │   └── pricing.css
    │   ├── js
    │   └── media
    ├── templates
    │   └── store
    │       ├── base.html
    │       ├── form.html
    │       ├── merch.html
    │       ├── renting.html
    │       └── selling.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change the `settings.py` like this:

```
# Static files config

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static'))]
```

And remove the `static` folder from inside the store folder and place it **next to other apps**.

And remove the `type` attribute in the **link tag** from the html file.

```
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have included `static` folder inside `store` just remove it from it and take outside and re run the project it will work fine.

Comment: no i did try this and unfortunately it didn’t work, i had to follow arash.shx’s steps, anyway thank you for your response

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).